# Unable to connect to gcloud

Tags: ssh, gcloud

I am having trouble connecting to a Google Cloud virtual instance. I started up the virtual instance and was able to login as normal using `gcloud beta compute ssh`.
I then tried transferring files to the instance using `gcloud compute scp --recurse <local_source> \ <user_name>@<instance>:<remote_path>`

I got a response of 'Updating project ssh metadata...', which I have never seen before when trying to transfer files. The file transfer failed:

```
?\240<username>@<IP>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

In addition, now I am not even able to log into the VM. When I try to log-in I get:

```
ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Operation timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
```

As far as I can tell, the firewall rules are still the default and allow connections through port 22. I am still able to log in to the instance through the browser window, but not from the command line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like there's something wrong with the firewall rules in your GCP project if you get `ssh: connect to host <IP> port 22: Operation timed out` error.

Create a new rule that allows for SSH connections:

`gcloud compute --project=xxxxxx firewall-rules create newrulename --direction=INGRESS --priority=999 --network=default --action=ALLOW --rules=tcp:22 --source-ranges=0.0.0.0/0`

I've changed the priority to 999 (higher than 1000) so it will overwrite the default ones (in case there is a rule that blocks port 22).

After that try the `gcloud compute ssh myinstancename` again and it should work as usual.